# Laravel 4 and folder structure

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have installed composer and create my project folder, however the welcome page of laravel will be  displayed only if i click on the /public folder (using my easyPHP server on Windows)  and not if i click on the project directory.

Is an .htaccess problem? Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

for security reasons, the `public` folder should be the root of the web server, so this is all normal.

Comment: ok thanks so much, but when i will put the application live(on an on line web server) the path couldn't be my Project/public.. so i need to create another .hataccess or it's ok in this way?

Comment: Morehover how can i pooint my virtualhost(unfortunatly i have windows so easyPHP) on the /public folder?? thanks so much

Comment: I'm afraid I've never setup hosting on Windows machines, so I wouldn't know where to start.